# Object is only visible to the left eye

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I have a `Unity` project using `MRTK`.

After I changed the `MRTK/Standard` shader with the following shader, it only renders the object to the left eye.

How can I render the object to both eyes?

```
Shader "HoloUS/BrightnessContrast"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Width("Width", Float) = 1
        _Center("Center", Float) = 0.5
    }
    
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct VInp
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct VOut
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Center;
            float _Width;

            VOut vert(VInp inp)
            {
                VOut o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(inp.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(inp.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(VOut inp) : SV_Target
            {
                float min = _Center - _Width / 2;
                return tex2D(_MainTex, inp.uv) * _Width + min;
            }
            
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using single pass vr, there are few changes in shader declaration, in order to recognise stereo texture input in single pass.

```
//add this in struct appdata
UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID

//add this in struct v2f
UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO

//replace sampler2D
UNITY_DECLARE_SCREENSPACE_TEXTURE(_MainTex);

//add these inside v2f vert()
UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(v2f, o);
UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
```

Additional link: [Single Pass Instanced rendering](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassInstancing.html)

Answer (score 2):

For shaders with Hololens and MRTK2, there is an upgrade path perhaps that needs to be clicked through:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/rendering/mrtk-standard-shader?q=shader&view=mrtkunity-2022-05

Also, Unity defines following on stereo rendering for HoloLens for shader script requirements:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRenderingHoloLens.html

From version of Unity, could not tell the specific version  and MRTK version using in sample above.  If have further details, perhaps can assist further too with community.

Comment: Thanks. This link was what I looking for https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassInstancing.html